# Can't get times back from python script

Tags: python

I am testing two python scripts, sunset.py which calls gettimes.py to get two times but I get nothing returned. I know gettimes.py is called as it prints the times but I can't print them from sunset.py
gettimes.py

```
from gettimes import main

arg1 = ''
arg2 = ''

main(arg1, arg2)

print 'Hour on ', arg1
print 'Hour off ', arg2
```

sunset.py

```
import ephem # to get sunrise and sunset
import datetime # import date and time modules
import time
import sys

def main(arg1, arg2):
  here = ephem.Observer() #determine position of observer
  here.lat = 'xx.xx085057'
  here.lon = '-x.xx781850'
  here.elevation = 43 #meters
  sun = ephem.Sun() #define sun as object

  arg1 = here.next_rising(sun).datetime().strftime('%H:%M')
  arg2 = here.next_setting(sun).datetime().strftime('%H:%M')
  print arg1, arg2

if __name__=='__main__':
  sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does not pass arguments by reference the way you think it does (it's not like C++ reference semantics). It's more like passing by pointer; you can mutate attributes of the object received, but if you reassign the name completely, you've lost the pointer to the original object (and the local name no longer has anything to do with the caller).

When you reassign `arg1` and `arg2` in `sunset.main`, you rebound the local names, but the callers variables are unchanged. The usual solution here is to just return the new values, not pass in garbage when the function doesn't need it:

```
def main():
  here = ephem.Observer() #determine position of observer
  here.lat = 'xx.xx085057'
  here.lon = '-x.xx781850'
  here.elevation = 43 #meters
  sun = ephem.Sun() #define sun as object

  arg1 = here.next_rising(sun).datetime().strftime('%H:%M')
  arg2 = here.next_setting(sun).datetime().strftime('%H:%M')
  return arg1, arg2

# I have no idea why you were passing argv stuff to main here,
# since it's not used, but this is a not too terrible way of handling it:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(*main())
```

And on the caller side:

```
from gettimes import main

arg1, arg2 = main()

print 'Hour on ', arg1
print 'Hour off ', arg2
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, both work, but I have also got rid of a few lines here that I didn't need and less is more when it comes to code

Answer (score 2):

Strings are not mutable.

Try it:

```
import ephem # to get sunrise and sunset
import datetime # import date and time modules
import time
import sys

def main():
  here = ephem.Observer() #determine position of observer
  here.lat = 'xx.xx085057'
  here.lon = '-x.xx781850'
  here.elevation = 43 #meters
  sun = ephem.Sun() #define sun as object

  arg1 = here.next_rising(sun).datetime().strftime('%H:%M')
  arg2 = here.next_setting(sun).datetime().strftime('%H:%M')

# print arg1, arg2
  return (arg1, arg2)

if __name__=='__main__':
  sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]))
```

.

```
from gettimes import main


arg1, arg2 = main()

print 'Hour on ', arg1
print 'Hour off ', arg2
```

Comment: I think you meant to say "String are not _mutable_ " or "Strings _are_ immutable". As written, you said the opposite of what you meant. And even so, the mutability of strings isn't relevant here; they rebound the local names in `main`, so mutable or not, they'd no longer be related to what the caller passed.

Comment: My mistake. Thanks.